# Find convergence of $\sum_{n=2}^{∞} \frac{1}{n\left(\left(\ln\left(n\right)\right)^3+\ln\left(n\right)\right)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{n=2}^{∞} \frac{1}{n\left(\left(\ln\left(n\right)\right)^3+\ln\left(n\right)\right)}$$

I know that there are several methods of finding the convergence of a series. The ratio test, the comparison test, the limit comparison test. There is also this theorem: If a series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ of real numbers converges then $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n = 0$.

**So can I everytime just apply this theorem instead of using all the tests?** For example in here,

$\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{1}{n\left(\left(\ln\left(n\right)\right)^3+\ln\left(n\right)\right)}\right) = 0$ So I can just conclude that  $\sum_{n=2}^{∞} \frac{1}{n\left(\left(\ln\left(n\right)\right)^3+\ln\left(n\right)\right)}$convergences?

It seems to me that most of the time I can just get away with using all that comparison by using this theorem or am I getting the wrong idea?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123774/discussion-on-question-by-mercurialkg-find-convergence-of-sum-n2-frac).

Answer (score 1):

Use for example [Cauchy's Condensation Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) for $\;a_n=\frac1{n\log^2n}\;$ after a first comparison (why can you? Check carefully the conditions to apply this test!):

$$2^na_{2^n}=\frac{2^n}{2^n\log^22^n}=\frac1{n^2\log^22}\le\frac1{n^2}$$

Comment: You are missing a $2$ under the final $\log$.

Comment: @Gary Thanks, indeed so. Edited.

Comment: @DonAntonio Hello, thanks for the answer. I actually haven't done the Cauchy condensation test before. My professor said I cannot use it. It is possible to use the comparison test to test the convergence instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can use comparison and integral test. The terms of the series are all positive and we have
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{n = 2}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{n(\log ^3 n + \log n)}}} & \le \sum\limits_{n = 2}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{n\log ^2 n}}}  < \frac{1}{{2\log ^2 2}} + \sum\limits_{n = 3}^\infty  {\int_{n - 1}^n {\frac{{dt}}{{t\log ^2 t}}} } 
\\ &
 = \frac{1}{{2\log ^2 2}} + \int_2^{ + \infty } {\frac{{dt}}{{t\log ^2 t}}}  = \frac{1}{{2\log ^2 2}} + \frac{1}{{\log 2}} <  + \infty 
\end{align*}
whence the series converges.